# html href to one page from different folder

Tags: html, href

I have edited this question:

At root, I have a working folder F (root/F), under F there is a folder B (root/F/B).

I have a folder A contains a php file a.php (root/A/a.php), containing a link to folder B:
`<div><a href="B/">link</a></div>`

In F, there is an index.php (root/F/index.php) includes the a.php in it, so index.php has a link to folder B;

There is a folder C under folder F. In C, there is another index.php (root/F/C/index.php), which also includes the a.php in it. But now the href becomes root/F/C/B/ instead of root/F/B/.

If I update a.php to `<div><a href="/B/">link</a></div>`, although href in root/F/C/index.php becomes root/F/B, which is what I want, href in root/F/index.php becomes root/B/.

So my question is how to get a universal href in a.php for all the pages in my working folder?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "/F/B" it will always go to "root/F/B".

Comment: i know what you mean, i didn't make it clear, i have edited the question

Comment: What you've updated in your question does not seem correct.  `/` should always go back to the root, it shouldn't be different based on what folder it is run in.  What you are describing sounds like what would happen if you were to use `../`

Comment: yes, it goes back to root. But i want it to go one level back if in folder root/F/C, and does not go back if in folder root/F.

Comment: oh...why I haven't considered that... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div><a href="/B/">link</a></div>
```

Put a absolute path.

Comment: i know what you mean, i didn't make it clear, i have edited the question